# Showing user his play store account in WebView Android

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I have a WebView in android that i am using for google account login using following url
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=googleplay
and authentication and then i redirect user to show him his google account store using 
https://play.google.com/store/account
And it is working fine for me.

But when after sometime i come back and again wants to show user his account then it is asking for login again.

How can prevent showing him login again and take him directly to his account ?

Things i have tried:- CookieManager setAcceptCookie

Comment: you need to persist cookies I think

Comment: I am already doing so , i have added CookieManager start and stop sync to my Activity